# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have been troubling to make the build on running `npm run build`.

I am getting

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not
> empty,rmdir
> '/var/www/html/abhinav/png-react/png-compressor/build/static'

Comment: Could you try deleting the build folder?

Comment: Nice! Glad it helped, could you mark the answer i posted as solution? This way other people that are facing the same issue can easily find the solution :) @Abhinav

Comment: Also that sweet sweet reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the `build` folder and running the `npm run build` command again will fix the issue.